# With Xcode 4.3 views don't load

Tags: ios, xcode

I have several projects that with the upgrade to Xcode 4.3 don't crash but don't load their views either.  Since it's a widespread problem, I wonder if I need to remake all the connections in the nib or some other global sort of change?  I hope I didn't move to 4.3 too soon!  Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your nib connections? Is that problem appears on simulator and device?

Comment: No, I haven't checked them... I'm guessing they are bad due to the upgrade, but I'm hoping to get some confirmation before proceeding.  I have a history of fixing unbroken things.

Comment: To be clear, I'm wondering if reconnecting the nib is automatically necessary with the upgrade to Xcode 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amateur Hour: After upgrading to Xcode 4.3, my projects for some reason started opening with Xcode 3.2  Back to work!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Xcode 4.3; App windows were not loading after clean compiles. I found an apparent (so far) fix/workaround by deleting the failing app's folder within this folder:

**~/Library/Saved Application State/**.

In Terminal:

**cd ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State**

(note the backslashes "\") Then delete the folder for the failing app:

**rm -fr *pgmname*.savedState/**

Or rename it:

**mv *pgmname*.savedState/ z-*pgmname*.savedState/**

Or maybe you can just rename it or trash it from Finder (I can't for some reason).